# Problem finding other examples of successor sets. Problem understanding successor sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Halmos Naive set theory (Self-study). I'm at chapter 11 (Set theory).
And I'm very confused by successor sets.

In the book the set of natural numbers *w* is stated to be the smaller of the successor set. But when I try to think of other successor set I can't seem to find any.

[The following website](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Successor_set) gives the example of $S = \{ 1, \sqrt{2}, 1 + \sqrt{2},...\}  $. Here I assume that $0$ can be included in the set *S* with no consequence.
From here on I am going to include $ 0$ in the set. I assume that this set continues with $ 2, \sqrt{2} + 2...$

But I don't understand that either. The problem that I have with the successor set *S* are the same problem I have with finding any other successor set than the set natural numbers *w*:

There are two ways that I"m  going on about this:

- First way; I suppose the following:

$\sqrt{2} + 1 = \sqrt(2)^+ = \{\sqrt{2}\}$

$\sqrt{2} + 2 = (\sqrt(2) + 1)^+ = \{\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} + 1\}$

...etc

But then I can only conclude that $\sqrt(2) = \emptyset $, But I think that is absurd because both $ 0 $ and $\sqrt(2) $ are included as separate elements in *S*

---

- Second way; I assume the following:

$ 0 = \emptyset$

$1 = 0^+ = \{0\}$

$\sqrt(2) = 1^+ = \{0, 1\}$

$ 2 = \sqrt(2)^+ = \{0, 1, \sqrt(2)\}$

...etc

But then I would get: *S* $\cap$ *w* $ = \{0, 1\}$, because $2_S$ != to $2_w$ neither is $3_S$ and $3_w$...

So the intersection is not a successor set.

---

So I have to be missing something. But I can't figure out what. Can you explain? Can you give examples of other successor sets? And How is S a successor set? What would be the intersection (I believe it should be *w*)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $S$, on the Web page you refer to, is constructed on the assumption that one already has a model of a system of axioms for the real number system - most likely the axioms for a complete ordered field - as well as a definition of the particular real number $\sqrt{2}$.

Halmos's book does not even define the rational number system, let alone the real number system; logically, it starts much further back.

Confusion arises because the same phrase, "successor set", is used in both texts. It is used because in both cases the intention is to provide a model of the Peano axioms (which are considered in the next section of Halmos's book). But the two developments cannot be mixed.

What one can do, though, is give an example of a "successor set", in the sense of the book, that is *analogous* to the example of a "successor set" that is given on the Web page.

The Web page starts with the elements $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$, neither of which is a successor of any element, and repeatedly adds $1$ to them both, thus:
$$
\{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \sqrt{2}, 1 + \sqrt{2}, 2 + \sqrt{2}, \ldots \}
$$

In Halmos's book, we don't have an order relation analogous to that which exists on the real number system, so we can't list a successor set in "increasing order", as the Web page does for its example; but that's not important.

In place of $\sqrt{2}$, we can pick an arbitrary set that doesn't belong to $\omega$, say $\alpha = \{\{\emptyset\}\}$. We can then repeatedly apply the successor operation to the two starting elements $\emptyset, \alpha$, thus:
$$
\{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}, \ldots,
\{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}, \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}\}, \ldots \}.
$$

Strictly speaking, it hasn't been shown that this set exists! But it might do well enough as an intuitive example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But isn't the set that you give the set of natural numbers? 0 = to the empty set, 1 = 0+ = {empty set,{empty set}}, 2 = 1+ = ...

Comment: Assuming I didn't mistype it, the list of elements splits into two parts. The first part, $\{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\},\ldots,\}$, is (or should be!) the set $\omega$. The second part, $\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}, \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}\},\ldots \}$, is (or should be!) a second copy of $\omega$, starting with $\alpha$ instead of $\emptyset$. (Incidentally, if you want the usual symbol for the empty set, you can get it in $\LaTeX{}$ by typing \emptyset, unless I mistyped that as well.)

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Thank you now I understand. And thank you for pointing out that I can use latex in the comments as well. I'm not very used to math.stackexchange. I appreciate your explanations in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The site where you found your example defines a "successor set" as

> A set $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ is called a successor set iff
>
> - $1\in S$
> - $\forall n\in S$; $n+1\in S$

Note that the second of these conditions say $n+1$ -- *not* $n\cup\{n\}$. And it explicitly says $S\subset \mathbb R$, so in this setting the elements of a successor set are *numbers* rather than abstract *sets*. You're assumed to know how to add real numbers to each other already.

You then manage to confuse yourself when you try to pretend this is the same definition you have seen elsewhere, which is based on $n\cup\{n\}$ to make a successor.

---

In a set-theoretic setting, with the $n\cup\{n\}$ definition we can make a different successor set by brute force -- just take $\omega$ plus something that is not already in $\omega$, such as $\{2,5\}$ and add all the successors of the latter:

$$ \begin{align} S = \{\; & 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,\ldots, \\
  & \{2,5\}, \{2,5,\{2,5\}\}, \{2,5,\{2,5\},\{2,5,\{2,5\}\}\}, \ldots \} \end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry to post an answer that is virtually a duplicate of yours, but I'd almost finished composing it when yours was posted, and I didn't have the heart to discard the work, as perhaps I should have done!

Comment: Okay thank you for the example